# Making a new column using loop in xts in R

Tags: r, loops, apply, xts

I'm new to R and facing a sort of problem.

I have xts data and I would like to make a new column according to these values.
Example:

```
>head(x1)
>                      Values
>"2014-09-01 00:00:01" -0.1
>"2014-09-01 00:00:02" 0.05
>"2014-09-01 00:00:03" 0.01
>"2014-09-01 00:00:04" -0.03
>"2014-09-01 00:00:05" 0.01
>"2014-09-01 00:00:06" -0.001
```

I would like to add a new column something like:

```
>                     Values  Signs
>"2014-09-01 00:00:01"  -0.1 Negetive
>"2014-09-01 00:00:02" 0.05  Positive
>"2014-09-01 00:00:03" 0.01  Positive
>"2014-09-01 00:00:04" -0.03 Negative
>"2014-09-01 00:00:05" 0.01  Positive
>"2014-09-01 00:00:06"-0.001 Negative
```

I've been trying some ways like

```
>x2 <- apply(x1, MARGIN = 1, 
+if(x1 > 0){
+           paste("Positive")
+          }else{
+                if(x1<0){
+                         paste("Negative")
+                        }
+               }
+           )
```

And it didn't work at all.
I know it's a very basic question but it's hard for me.
Thanks for any help.

When I did dput(head(sep4diff1)) (sep4diff1 is the real name of my data object), I got:

```
x1 <- structure(c(NA, -0.00200000000000955, -0.000999999999990564, 
0, 0, 0, NA, 0.000999999999990564, -0.00199999999999534, 0, 0, 
0), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "", index
=structure(c(1409756400.675, 
1409756401.938, 1409756402.414, 1409756403.173, 1409756404.173, 
1409756405.173), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(6L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Bid", "Ask")))
```

In the previous example there is just one column but actually I have two columns.
And value could be zero, so I have to make a column whose "Positive", "Negative" or "Zero".
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe `with(x1, ifelse(Values > 0, "Positive", "Negative")` but what if Values equal zero?

Comment: Oh you're right I've got also add "Zero" when the value is zero.

Comment: you cannot mix classes in an `xts`.  If you add a column containing words, the whole xts is going to become `character`

Comment: Thanks for comment. Does it mean that I've got to convert the class of the xts data in advance?

Comment: honestly, it doesn't look like you've even got an xts object.  Can you add the output of `dput(head(x1))` to your question?  You could add a column that has a 1 for positive and a -1 for negative, but if you add a column with "Negetive" and "Positive" your other column is going to become `character` too.

Comment: Okay, then I would like to 'make' a new column instead of adding.
Do you think it is possible using     with    ?

Comment: I'd think `x1$sign <- sign(x1$Bid)` would be close enough, but I don't know why you want/need text.